# Understanding try catch block

Tags: php, try-catch

I am confused about the whole try catch block. I understand if an exception is thrown it execute the catch block, however I have a question regarding using return inside the try block.

```
try {

    //other logic is here

    //this is in laravel and sends the user back and should stop operation
    if (foo != bar) {
       return Redirect::back()->with_message('This auction is closed.', 'error');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

So my question is: is it okay to end operation inside the try block? Will I ever encounter an error where the return is ignored (or thought of as an exception?) and the code continues? Again, I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a perfectly valid way to write that code.

The one case where your code will keep running after control exits the `try` or `catch` block is in PHP 5.5, which finally adopted the `finally` block from other languages, and can be used to run cleanup code that must always execute after the `try` block does, regardless of whether an exception got thrown.

But you're probably not using 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is ok. If for any reason Redirect::back or the with_message method raise an exception you will return the error message instead